# KO template with filter based on variable

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array of items, and I want to group them into multiple sections based on the data within that array.  I'm using KO if conditionals successfully, but I have to repeat the section markup and conditional for each section I want.  I want to convert the section to a template to avoid repetition, but I don't know how to include the if condition in the template using a variable rank.  Is there a way to pass a variable to a template and reference that variable within the template?

Here is the HTML:

```
<strong>Rank 1:</strong><br/>
<ul data-rank="1" data-bind="foreach: listItems">
    <!-- ko if: rank == 1 -->
    <li data-bind="text: name + ' (' + rank + ')'"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>

<strong>Rank 2:</strong><br/>
<ul data-rank="2" data-bind="foreach: listItems">
    <!-- ko if: rank == 2 -->
    <li data-bind="text: name + ' (' + rank + ')'"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>

<strong>Rank 3:</strong><br/>
<ul data-rank="3" data-bind="foreach: listItems">
    <!-- ko if: rank == 3 -->
    <li data-bind="text: name + ' (' + rank + ')'"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var viewModel = {};

    viewModel.listItems = ko.observableArray();
    viewModel.listItems.push({name: "A", rank: 1});
    viewModel.listItems.push({name: "B", rank: 1});
    viewModel.listItems.push({name: "C", rank: 2});
    viewModel.listItems.push({name: "D", rank: 2});
    viewModel.listItems.push({name: "E", rank: 1});
    viewModel.listItems.push({name: "F", rank: 3});
    viewModel.listItems.push({name: "G", rank: 2});

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

And a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RationalGeek/9eftr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a filter function on the viewmodel:

```
viewModel.filterByRank = function(rank) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.listItems(), function(item) {
        return item.rank == rank;
    });
}
```

And then use this function in the bindings:

```
<strong>Rank 1:</strong><br/>
<ul data-rank="1" 
    data-bind="template: { name: 'temp', foreach: filterByRank(1) }">
</ul>

<strong>Rank 2:</strong><br/>
<ul data-rank="2" 
    data-bind="template: { name: 'temp', foreach: filterByRank(2) }">
</ul>

<strong>Rank 3:</strong><br/>
<ul data-rank="3" 
    data-bind="template: { name: 'temp', foreach: filterByRank(3) }">
</ul>

<script id="temp" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="text: name + ' (' + rank + ')'"></li>
</script>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9dz2/).

Or you can move your whole markup to a template and use it like:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'temp', data: { rank: 1, items: filterByRank(1) } } -->
<!-- /ko -->

<script id="temp" type="text/html">
    <strong>Rank <!-- ko: text: rank --><!-- /ko --></strong>
    <br/>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: items, attr: { 'data-rank': rank}">
        <li data-bind="text: name + ' (' + rank + ')'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vbpt/).

Comment: This gets me some part of the way there, as I no longer have to repeat the markup for the items (the <li> in this demo).  However, I also don't want to repeat the <ul> or <strong> elements.

Comment: @RationalGeek you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/d9dz2/1/ or using a different approach to populate the template: http://jsfiddle.net/d9dz2/2/

Comment: Accepting as answer.  This pointed me toward what I ended up doing: http://jsfiddle.net/RationalGeek/fTXX4/